# Form receiving notification of raised event in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, user-controls

I still can't find anything on this. But in my app I have a main form (Form1) and inside that form is a UserControl. When a person clicks on an item in the ListView of that usercontrol, I want to know about it (ItemSelectionChanged Event) inside the Form1 form. Any suggestions/advice on this?

Thank you

Comment: The UserControl is just a class. Give that class a public event. Let the form subscribe to that event. When the ItemSelectionChanged event happens in the user control, it should raise its public event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside usercontrol, define an event, such as

```
Event listviewItemChanged(ByVal itemIndex as integer)
```

Then, in the Listview ItemSelectionChanged event inside usercontrol, raise the usercontrol's listviewItemChanged event:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemSelectionChanged
RaiseEvent listviewItemChanged(e.ItemIndex)
End Sub
```

And finally, in Form1, handle the usercontrol.listviewItemchanged event:

```
Public Sub usercontrol_listviewItemChanged(ByVal itemIndex as Integer) Handles usercontrol.listviewItemChanged
...
end sub
```